# Windows 10 and chrome, font issue after migrating from windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, windows-10

I've been experiencing this issues with the font since I've updated to windows 10 from windows 8.1.

The main issue is the font rendering on the sites that default to "Helvetica Neue", ie.

[image]

(viewing Stack Overflow)

this differs a lot from Firefox

[image]

and is really hard to read for me. Is there any way to make it render properly. Btw this also happens on IE Edge.

EDIT:
A per Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 m this issue seems resolved
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open in Chrome `chrome://flags` and disable `DirectWrite`. DirectWrite is part of DirectX API and it provides text rendering but it is problematic and it is causing lot of issues with text.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer to the question, but it would be even better if you [edit] your answer and explain what this setting does and why it solves the OP's problem. (Especially since the OP says the same thing happens with a different web browser.)

Comment: Lot of people have issues with Direct Write after updating to Windows 10. Microsoft Edge is also using Direct Write, Firefox is not (by default).

Comment: @Michalko thanks, actually this almost fixes this but why does it look different from firefox (http://i.imgur.com/6aR8Mv6.png left chrome, right firefox), though is much better than before

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that Chrome made some changes with the flags in the last version and now the flag you need to disable is `chrome://flags/#enable-font-cache-scaling` and restart your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling DirectWrite in Chrome is just a bandaid, it Masks the problem, doesn't actually fix it.

Some incorrectly written fonts will map over other fonts, like Arial.ttf. This has not been a problem until Windows 10 and the changes made with DirectWrite.

FIX:
If you are in Windows 10, there are no fonts older than 1/26/2012 installed by default. Find all fonts older than this date, and delete them while Chrome or any other application with font problems is open. The font causing the problem (taking over Arial.ttf) will not be able to be deleted until Chrome, etc. is closed. Restore the fonts you just deleted except for the font that wouldn't let you delete it. If the problem is still not solved, try again. I was able to fix my pc, and many others using this method, and this method only, other than a clean install with no additional fonts installed afterwards.

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't find any font older than 1/26/2012, my oldest font dates 2013

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290)

**Step 1: Use the text tuner**

1. On your Windows computer, click the Start menu: Start menu or Start menu.
2. In the search box, type ClearType.
3. Click **Adjust ClearType Text**.
4. In the ClearType Text Tuner, check the box next to "Turn on ClearType."
5. Click Next, then complete the steps.
6. Click Finish.

**Step 2: Change your Windows appearance settings**

If Step 1 doesn't work, try changing your Windows appearance settings. This step is most helpful for displays with high resolution.

1. On your Windows computer, click the Start menu: Start menu or Start menu.
   In the search box, type Appearance.
2. Click "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows."
3. Next to "Smooth edges of screen fonts," uncheck the box.
4. Click Apply.
5. Open Chrome again.